# Unable to access postgres running inside docker container using psql command on terminal

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, sequelize.js

I have postgres running inside docker container and I am able to access the postgres database using the below steps -

1. docker exec -it {container-id} bash
2. psql -U test postsdb

and I am in -

```
postsdb #
```

Also have installed kitematic and able to verify that docker pusblished **IP:PORT** is **localhost:5432**

but my app is not able to connect to postgres and giving the error -

```
SequelizeConnectionError: role "coder" does not exist
```

to debug this i tried connected to db using the postgres url from command line and what I saw strange is, it's also giving the same error

the command I used which is configured in my app as well is -

```
psql postgres://test:password@localhost:5432/postsdb
```

Comment: How did you start your postgres container? check this article on how to connect to a postgres container from the localhost (psql cli): https://medium.com/@lvthillo/connect-from-local-machine-to-postgresql-docker-container-f785f00461a7

Comment: If your app is running on localhost you can also use localhost:5432, if your app is running in docker too you should use a named docker bridge network so container can communicate using their container name. Because pointing to localhost from inside a container will point to the localhost of the container itself and not the host.

Comment: @lvthillo for the response, yeah I read your blog even before raising the question here. Though I don't how but I resolved it just by restarting my machine, still wondering what could have gone earlier ?